# Запись вызова метода в лог

Tags: c#, атрибуты, .net, рефлексия

Есть такой код:

```
public class Foo
{
    [Log("Calling bar")]
    public void Bar()
    {
    }
}
```

Как сделать, чтобы при вызове метода `Bar` что-то писалось в лог?
Хотелось бы какое-нибудь событие типа `OnCall`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Аспектно-ориентированное программирование](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

> Ведение лога и обработка ошибок — типичные примеры сквозной функциональности.

[PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/features) - одна из лучших библиотек АОП для c#

Вот пример аспекта:

```
public class LogAttribute : PostSharp.Aspects.OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    // Выполняется перед входом в метод.
    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Входим в метод {0} класса {1}", args.Method.Name, args.Method.DeclaringType.FullName);

    }

    // Выполняется при успешном завершении работы метода
    public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Метод {0} класса {1} успешно отработал", args.Method.Name, args.Method.DeclaringType.FullName);
    }
}
```

[Быстрый старт](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/documentation)

[PostSharp. Решение задач логгирования и аудита](http://habrahabr.ru/post/124860/)

[Несколько полезных аспектов для PostSharp](http://habrahabr.ru/post/62232/)

Comment: Спасибо. Я уже думал про PostSharp. Но надеялся что есть более простое решение проблемы. Думаю все-таки придется использовать АОП